# Rails Asset Pipeline not including same file in multiple manifests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, sprockets

This is my application.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
//= stub subscriptions
```

It has always worked as expected and `subscription.js` is another file which is compiled separately.

If I add this line at the top of `subscriptions.js`:

```
//= require jquery
```

The `subscriptions.js` is compiled as expected and includes jQuery, but **jQuery disappears from `application.js`**: in the browser console I get errors like 
`ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined`.

**I cannot find a way to have jquery compiled/included in both the manifest files.**

I use a development environment with Rails 4.2.4 + Puma and the default `jquery-rails` gem.

Comment: I have also tried to change the asset version and restart the server but the issue persists.

Answer (score 0):

It's the expected behavior of the `stub` directive: not only `subscriptions` but **also all its dependencies will be stubbed**.

The only solution is to avoid using `require_tree` and `stub`.